# push string to array from another activity

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

[my aplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4Tf.jpg)

I have 2 activity, the first is CategoryActivity and the second is QuestionActivity.
in CategoryActivity i have a recyclerview which lists categories, and also in Category Activity, i have an array. When i click eksterior, it will go to questionActivity, and when i click submit, it will back to CategoryActivity and send data to CategotyActivity. the data sent was entered into the array, so the array will be like this: array [] = {“1”}; then i click the second item in recyclerview which is interior, then it will go to QuestionActivity again, when i click submit, it will send data to CategoryActivity and add it into the previous array, so the array will be like this :  array [] = {“1”,”1”}; and so on until the items on the recyclerview run out. I have tried like this :

**QuestionActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

    button_save.setOnClickListener(){
        val intent = Intent(this@ResultActivity, KategoriActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(KategoriActivity.Companion.ARRAY, "1")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

**CategoryActivity.kt**

```
var list = arrayOf(intent.getStringExtra(ARRAY))
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)
    Toast.makeText(this@KategoriActivity, ""+ list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


}
companion object {
    val ARRAY = "array"

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this@KategoriActivity, ""+ list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    if (list.size == kategoriDatas!!.size){
        onBackPressed()
    } else {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage("You Must Finish All The Category")

        // add a button
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)

        // create and show the alert dialog
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
    }
```

and the problem is when i open category activity the app is stopped, and the log is say `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

and the data can not push to the array, please help me

Comment: Put your `var list = arrayOf(intent.getStringExtra(ARRAY))` below `setContentView`.

Comment: the app doesn't stoped but the toast is show [Ljava.lang.String;@8e6837c

Comment: @Prexx i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the intent after the activity has been created. In order to make sure of it it's best if you place the code that's gonna get the extras from Intents inside your onCreate.

Like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)
    Toast.makeText(this@KategoriActivity, ""+ list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    var list = arrayOf(intent.getStringExtra(ARRAY))
}
```

If you want to have an Application class that holds information:

```
class MyApplication : Application(){
var list = emptyArray<String>()

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
  }
}
```

To use it in your activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category)
    Toast.makeText(this@KategoriActivity, ""+ list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    var list = (application as MyApplication).list
   // you can than use it to update or retrieve values from it
}
```

Comment: yes but the toast is show [Ljava.lang.String;@8e6837c

Comment: Because you are getting the extra as an array.
if you want just the string you are currently passing in your example("1") you should do var extra = intent.getStringExtra(ARRAY).

More if you want to have a consistent array across multiple activities passing it through activities back and forth it's not the best solution. You should have a repository somewhere with the array or an Application class that holds that array for the entire time your application is running.

Comment: can you give me the example?

Comment: I'll give you an example for Application class.
As for the repo you should consider using the new Android Components that have a direct connection to a recycler view.
The direct link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/
A github example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower

I have edited my answer for the application

Comment: Try to convert your array to String with `Arrays.toString(list)` or with `list.joinToString()`